# Receive response after sending UDP broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, udp, broadcast, winsock2

I'm having a problem with broadcast: I can send the message, the receivers receive it and send it back, but I can't get those responses. It shows on wireshark, though, so it's there.

Here's what I do on the sender's end:

- create the socket
- set the broadcast option to 1
- set it non-blocking
- set it to the target port & broadcast IP, using connect
- send the message
- keep receiving on it using recv() to get the response

But I don't get the response in that recv, even though it shows on Wireshark and it's not rejected by the computer (no ICMP message).

Is there something wrong with what that process, or am I not looking at the right place?

(by the way, when using no broadcast option and the target IP, it works fine)

Comment: Can you show some code please?  Many possible coding bugs could exist in the approach you outline in place of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `connect()`, which associates the socket with a specific remote IP:Port, and thus the socket will only be able to `recv()` packets from that specific remote IP:Port and no other.  You are "connecting" to the broadcast IP, which allows you to `send()` broadcast packets, but you are going to receive responses from individual peer IPs, so `recv()` will silently discard all of the responses since the source IPs do not match the IP you are connected to.

When you are doing direct peer-to-peer communications, it makes sense to use `connect()`, `send()`, and `recv()` and let the socket manage the IPs for you.  But when broadcasting, DO NOT use `connect()`!  Use `sendto()` instead of `send()` to send packets to the broadcast IP, and then use `recvfrom()` instead of `recv()` to allow responses from any peer IP (`recvfrom()` will tell you the source IP that each packet comes from).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I used recvfrom at first by the way (and now), I changed it to recv when I was trying to figure out what was wrong.